# Understanding Gas Fees for NFTs

Tags: gas, gas-limit, gas-price, gas-estimate

I am going to mint a collection of 10,000 NFTs. However, I've become very concerned over the gas costs associated with such an endeavor. I was wondering if someone could help me understand the following:

1. When I created an account on OpenSea there was a one time gas fee. After that I can mint as many NFTs and create as many collections as I want all for free. How is this possible?
2. If I programmatically mint NFTs on the mainnet for example by following [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-an-nft-and-render-on-opensea-marketplace/), I must pay the gas price when I deploy the contract and for each NFT I mint right? Seems like it will cost a fortune to mint 10,000 if I have to pay a substantial gas price for each mint.
3. I've looked at [Cargo](https://docs.cargo.build/cargo-js/getting-started-with-cargo-js) which is supposed to be designed for batch minting but it seems like there is actually a lot of hidden costs.
4. Is there an inexpensive solution (<US$500) for me to deploy 10,000 NFTs other than uploading them one by one manually onto OpenSea?

Answer (score 1):

I have no deep understanding of NFT's but I want to share my guesses.

1. They are probably using classical off-chain methods (using a database) to hold your created NFT until someone pays for transferring it. I think there's no meaning in paying entrance price. They also take commissions for every transfer that is around %2.5
2. Ethereum network is super expensive. Solution for that using sidechains or layer2 solutions.
3. IDK anything about Cargo.
4. The solution that I can offer is this:

   - Deploy all of your NFT's to [xdaichain](https://www.xdaichain.com/). That side chain has super low fees. (I'have deployed an NFT for 0.01XDAI which is 0.01$).
   - List them on https://xdai.unique.one/ and wait until some sales happen.
   - When you see which of your NFT's are being sold you can bridge them to the main net. (But I don't know how :)

**Notes:**

- Go check [nifty.ink](https://nifty.ink) draw something and mint to see what it costs. (It's really deploying your NFT to the chain.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSea doesn't actually mint your NFT until someone buys it. So the buyer is usually in-charge of the fee's. OpenSea just stores the image in their database and then does the minting later.

I'm in the same dilemma you're in. I tried looping a mint function, but ultimately you'll be end up paying for each mint.

If I find anything at my end i'll be sure to update.